# how to return all rows in table as mysqli objects in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
class User {

    public function find_all_users(){
        global $db;
        $result=$db->select("SELECT * FROM users");
         while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
             return $obj;
         }
   }
```

In another file

```
$user=new User();
$user->find_all_users();
```

I want to get the returned `$obj` variable and print all the rows in the table.

But I have a error here. It just prints the first row again and again.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: For return all data use `while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
         $data[]= $obj;
     }return $data;` don't forget to define $data array before it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is return when your while loop run first time.
Try your code as:

```
public function find_all_users(){
   $data = array();
   global $db;
   $result=$db->select("SELECT * FROM users");
   while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      $data[] = $obj;
   }
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: Just need to define `$data` array

Comment: Now it's looking fine!!

Answer (score 3):

You want to create an array of your results.

So, change this:

```
while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    return $obj;
}
```

To this:

```
$results = [];
while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $results[] = $obj;
}
return $results;
```